# Chat View built with MessageKit never scrolls to last message with a picture

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, messagekit

I'm building a chat view for my app with [MessageKit](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit). Image messages are something that this chat view will support. I'm currently having an issue where if the last message is a picture message, the message won't be properly displayed:

I'm loading all my messages in `viewDidLoad`, and then updating the `MessagesCollectionView` in `viewWillAppear`:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        messagesCollectionView.reloadData()
        messagesCollectionView.scrollToLastItem()
    }
```

How do I get image messages to be properly displayed?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the issue was that these updates were not being called on the right thread; modifying the code to the below solved the issue:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.messagesCollectionView.reloadData()
        self.messagesCollectionView.scrollToLastItem()
    }
}
```